# Is IIS "time-taken" forward looking or reverse looking?

Tags: iis

I am trying to analyze IIS logs for some timeout issues that we see from time to time. Is IIS "time-taken" forward looking or reverse looking?

In other words, does "date"/"time" represent the time when the request started or the time when it completed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time when it completed.

Note: The value in the time-taken field does not include network time if one of the following conditions is true:

- The response size is less than or equal to 2 KB, and the response size is from memory.
- TCP buffering is used. Applications that use HTTPAPI.dll can set the HTTP_SEND_RESPONSE_FLAG_BUFFER_DATA flag to enable TCP buffering on Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 and later. This allows the server to send all of the response data to the client without having to wait for the client’s corresponding acknowledgements.

More information:

**Description of the time-taken field in IIS 6.0 and IIS 7.0 HTTP logging**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944884

http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-logfile.html

Also note that the csBytes and scBytes do not necessarily reflect the amount of data in the request.  For example, a device may send a 3,500 character uriQuery, but the combined bytes may only be 1,000 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Date, time and time-taken are separate log fields, so which ones are you interested in exactly?

From the IIS Help:

**Date (date):** Logs the date on which the request occurred.

**Time (time):** Logs the time, in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), at which the request occurred.

**Time Taken (time-taken):** Logs the length of time that the action took in milliseconds.